# ImportError: cannot import name '_psutil_linux' from 'psutil' on AWS EC2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, psutil

I am running an EC2 instance on AWS and am having errors using python packages. I have installed both `psutil` and `stanfordcorenlp` using `pip` yet when I try to import I get the following error:

```
>>> from stanfordcorenlp import StanfordCoreNLP
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ec2-user/maxio-efs/stanfordcorenlp/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from stanfordcorenlp.corenlp import StanfordCoreNLP
  File "/home/ec2-user/maxio-efs/stanfordcorenlp/corenlp.py", line 14, in <module>
    import psutil
  File "/home/ec2-user/maxio-efs/psutil/__init__.py", line 99, in <module>
    from . import _pslinux as _psplatform
  File "/home/ec2-user/maxio-efs/psutil/_pslinux.py", line 26, in <module>
    from . import _psutil_linux as cext
ImportError: cannot import name '_psutil_linux' from 'psutil' (/home/ec2-user/maxio-efs/psutil/__init__.py)
```

Even importing `psutil` doesn't seem to work

```
>>> import psutil
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ec2-user/maxio-efs/psutil/__init__.py", line 99, in <module>
    from . import _pslinux as _psplatform
  File "/home/ec2-user/maxio-efs/psutil/_pslinux.py", line 26, in <module>
    from . import _psutil_linux as cext
ImportError: cannot import name '_psutil_linux' from 'psutil' (/home/ec2-user/maxio-efs/psutil/__init__.py)
```

I have tried many solutions, including installing `python-devel`. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I was executing code from the wrong directory. I had mounted an EFS named `maxio-efs` with a file structure:

```
SSH POINT/
    maxio-efs/
        stanfordcorenlp
        psutil
        (other python packages)
```

The above error only occurred when running a python script from *inside* the `maxio-efs` directory. I needed to be anywhere else in order for python to be able to find the correct packages. By running python scripts from the same directory level as `maxio-efs`, the issue went away.